# How to find coefficient of variation

Tags: self-study, dispersion

Suppose  2x−3y=  5  is  the  relation  between  the  variables x and y .If  the variance of x be 1.44 and y has mean 1, then calculate the coefficient of variation of x

Comment: Please read about the self study tag and CV policies about homework questions and the self-study tag and act accordingly: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: Can you please explain where you're stuck?

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer as if this had a self-study tag:

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation

> The coefficient of variation (CV) is defined as the ratio of the standard deviation $\sigma$ to the mean $\mu$.

The mean of $y$ is explicitly stated, so no problem with that. The standard deviation of $y$ will in some way or another depend on the standard deviation of $x$. To find out, you might want to change the equation to something in the form of $y=\dots$